# Visual Composer attach media file needed

Tags: wordpress

Do I need to create new param type since there is no "attach_file"-type in https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=524332#vc_map()-Availabletypevalues

How come this kind of element is missing?

What I need is "Attach file"-button to backend.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this too. Did you find anything useful? I presume it can be handled via the WP core media screen by attaching a correct script as the third parameter to the `vc_add_shortcode_param` call.

Answer (score 20):

I have just had the same issue as you and the is what I came up with.

This allows for adding a visual composer content element in which you can select any file from the WordPress media manager (and remove the file selection).

### Separate this from the rest of your functions (use a modular approach).

In your templates `functions.php` add

```
/**
 * Visual Composer Functions
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/functions/vc-functions.php';
```

### Add your new shortcode param

In `your_template/functions/vc-functions.php` add

```
/**
 * Add file picker shartcode param.
 *
 * @param array $settings   Array of param seetings.
 * @param int   $value      Param value.
 */
function file_picker_settings_field( $settings, $value ) {
  $output = '';
  $select_file_class = '';
  $remove_file_class = ' hidden';
  $attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $value );
  if ( $attachment_url ) {
    $select_file_class = ' hidden';
    $remove_file_class = '';
  }
  $output .= '<div class="file_picker_block">
                <div class="' . esc_attr( $settings['type'] ) . '_display">' .
                  $attachment_url .
                '</div>
                <input type="hidden" name="' . esc_attr( $settings['param_name'] ) . '" class="wpb_vc_param_value wpb-textinput ' .
                 esc_attr( $settings['param_name'] ) . ' ' .
                 esc_attr( $settings['type'] ) . '_field" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" />
                <button class="button file-picker-button' . $select_file_class . '">Select File</button>
                <button class="button file-remover-button' . $remove_file_class . '">Remove File</button>
              </div>
              ';
  return $output;
}
vc_add_shortcode_param( 'file_picker', 'file_picker_settings_field', get_template_directory_uri() . '/vc_extend/file_picker.js' );
```

@ojrask was right - note the 3rd param of `vc_add_shortcode_param`. This is where we add the script for the media manager.

Note that this *saves* the attachment id but *shows* the url. Using the attachment id is better for use in other WP functions (handy when you want to do things for the front end output).

### Add your js

In `your_template/vc_extend/file_picker.js` add

```
!function($) {

  var _custom_media = true,
      _orig_send_attachment = wp.media.editor.send.attachment

  $( '#vc_ui-panel-edit-element .file-picker-button' ).click( function( e ) {
    var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment,
        file_picker_button = $( this ),
        file_remover_button = $( this ).parent().find( '.file-remover-button' ),
        input = $( this ).parent().find( '.file_picker_field' ),
        display = $( this ).parent().find( '.file_picker_display' );

    _custom_media = true;
    wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function( props, attachment ) {
      if ( _custom_media ) {
        display.html( attachment.url );
        input.val( attachment.id );
        file_picker_button.addClass( 'hidden' );
        file_remover_button.removeClass( 'hidden' );
      } else {
        return _orig_send_attachment.apply( this, [props, attachment] );
      };
    }

    wp.media.editor.open( file_picker_button );
    return false;
  });

  $( '#vc_ui-panel-edit-element .file-remover-button' ).click( function( e ) {
    var file_picker_button = $( this ).parent().find( '.file-picker-button' ),
        file_remover_button = $( this ),
        input = $( this ).parent().find( '.file_picker_field' ),
        display = $( this ).parent().find( '.file_picker_display' );

    display.html( '' );
    input.val( '' );
    file_picker_button.removeClass( 'hidden' );
    file_remover_button.addClass( 'hidden' );
  });

  $( '.add_media' ).on( 'click', function() {
    _custom_media = false;
  } );

}(window.jQuery);
```

### Use your newly created param type

The param can now be used in you vc_map(). This should also go in `your_template/functions/vc-functions.php` and should be something like

```
vc_map( array(
  'name' => __( 'your_element_name', 'js_composer' ),
  'base' => 'your_element_base',
  'content_element' => true,
  'class' => '',
  'icon' => 'icon-wpb-images-stack',
  'params' => array(
    array(
      'type' => 'file_picker',
      'class' => '',
      'heading' => __( 'Attach Media', 'js_composer' ),
      'param_name' => 'file_picker',
      'value' => '',
    ),
  ),
) );
```

### Output

To show the output on the front end create the file `your_template/vc_templates/your_element_base.php` and add something like

```
echo wp_get_attachment_url( $atts['file_picker'] );
```

This will output just the url to whatever file was selected.

The following resources were useful in making this:

vc_map docs https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=524332

creating new param types https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/display/VC/Create+New+Param+Type

adding the media manager script https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82874/99164

Comment: Thanks, man this works like a charm :). Do you have any idea how to make it work with param groupd? Right now it works well in single param, but in param group only 1st one works well :)

Comment: Little late :) but I just found it. To make it work for multiple elements just update click action in file_picker.js. Using ' $( '#vc_ui-panel-edit-element .file-picker-button' ).click( function( e ) { ' targets only elements renedered on page load. To support multiple elements added in custom widget after page load you need to change click action to on('click') 
'  $(document).on('click', '#vc_ui-panel-edit-element .file-picker-button', function ( e ) '
the same you need to do for .file-remover-button.